# typing an object with unknown data includes keys

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
type Country = {
  [key: string]: number | string | object | string[];
};

interface AboutCountry {
  infoCountry: Country[];
}

const props = defineProps<AboutCountry>();
/*create map*/
 marker.bindPopup(`${props.infoCountry[props.index].capital[0]}, ${props.infoCountry[props.index].name.common}`
```

When accessing `props.infoCountries[props.index].capital[0]` an error occurs:

```
The element is implicitly of type "any" because an expression of type "0" cannot be used to index the type "string | number | logical | object | a thread[]'.
     Property '0' does not exist for type 'string | number | logical | object | a thread[]'.
```

`infoCountry` - response from the server that I forward props in `map.vue`.

I think the problem is in the interface, but I don’t understand how to solve it.

Comment: We need to see the ``InfoCountry` type.

Comment: Im edited question